# How to add an example in a swagger endpoint so it it becomes easy to understand for the purpose of testing?

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have a post method in my swagger as endpoint. There I want to see some example relevant to it either in request body or in response.
My endpoint is basically for login so it accepts user name and password. So there I want an example for a sample user name and password so that it becomes easy to understand that how this endpoint is taking input.

My code for the endpoint.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Web.WebApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AuthenticateUserController : ControllerBase
    {
        public IConfiguration _configuration;
        public AuthenticateUserController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Login")]
        public async void Post(string userName, string password)
        {
             //code for login
        }
      }
    }
```

Something like this, but without using models.
[image]